# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have the following string that I am trying to convert into a dictionary in python :

```
   data =  "{'ABC - 1 check NEW_PAGE': 'red', 'CDE - 2 checks SQL_DATA': 'black', 'The temporary file generated contains the following errors : ['20235874;172426;admin_AB_34;S_DEB;100;FC_SUCCESS_F']': 'red'}"
```

What I am trying to use in python is the following lines of code :

```
data = data.replace("'", "\"")
data = json.loads(data)
```

I get the following error :

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 187 (char 186)
```

Could someone help me with a solution ? It would really be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You're escaping `'`, but it is not necessary when is between `"`:

```
data = data.replace("'", "\"")
data = json.loads(data)
```

But you'll probably hit another issue with the end of the data string `"'The temporary file generated contains the following errors : ['20235874;172426;admin_AB_34;S_DEB;100;FC_SUCCESS_F']'; 'red'"`. Which seems to be invalid json string.

Comment: That's a typo, I corrected it. It's ": 'red'" insted of "; 'red'"
The other issue that I am having after I used your solution is : json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 186 (char 185)

Comment: The remaining issue is with `['20235874;172426;admin_AB_34;S_DEB;100;FC_SUCCESS_F']` which would become `["20235874;172426;admin_AB_34;S_DEB;100;FC_SUCCESS_F"]` after replacement of `'` with `"`.

You can hack it for this exact use case using:
`data = data.replace("': '", "\": \"").replace("', '", "\", \"").replace("{'", "{\"").replace("'}", "\"}"))`

But that may break other use cases. I would recommend to find out how receive valid json at the first place.